# Set USB keyboard status in C#

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard, usb

I need to send output reports to a USB "keyboard", but Windows returns an invalid handle when using CreateFile on the USB device.  This is because Windows has the device open in exclusive mode.  How do I still send output reports to the keyboard?

I have already looked into the HidP_Xxxx functions, but they all require the CreateFile to succeed with a valid handle.  Also the Direct Input's SendDeviceData's documentation says that no device will work with it and to use HID instead.  The link to HID documentation is broken on that page.

Comment: A keyboard, USB or not, is an input device, not an output device. How do you expect to do any output to a keyboard? Also, where is the code?

Comment: USB keyboard support writing a report with the LED status.  The "keyboard" I am trying to talk to is actually a barcode scanner and the documentation states to send the 1 byte output reports with the LED status bits set/cleared in a specific order.  This is needed to get the barcode scanner into the correct mode.

Comment: Try HIDAPI: http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/

Comment: @DavidGrayson HIDAPI still requires the ability to open the USB device with CreateFile.  This is hidden inside the hid_open call.  The hid_open will fail when trying to open a USB keyboard class device. See [https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/issues/247](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/issues/247)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is an issue of the driver (the `.inf` file) of the barcode scanner and some specific keys it sets in registry, see the following links

- http://www.cypress.com/knowledge-base-article/exclusive-access-usb-device
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563827(v=vs.85).aspx (specifying exclusive access to device objects)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548407(v=vs.85).aspx (IoCreateDeviceSecure routine)
- **https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/install/inf-addreg-directive**
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn790026(v=vs.85).aspx (register and initialize the barcode scanner driver)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ee416848(v=vs.85).aspx (Cooperative levels)

maybe use a program like `USBDeview` to clean the registry and reinstall the scanner again (check the inf file for the `AddReg` entry) or try to remove the *exclusive access* registry key for the barcode scanner manually

in addition the windows 10 `hidscanner.dll` seems to be buggy https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/pos-hid-barcode-scanner-drivers-being-deleted/206b5354-06e0-47cb-98b8-805f525e130e ,  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-with-pos-hid-barcode-scanner/2adc8ea9-556c-4b85-98fe-3b625c37ab76

Comment: The barcode scanner attaches to the system as a USB keyboard class device and uses the "driverless" HID setup.  There is no .inf file to correct for the behavior of Windows taking exclusive access to the USB keyboard class devices.  The exclusive access to USB keyboard class devices is hard coded into the Windows device management system.  They do this for security reasons (i.e. attempting to block keyloggers from just opening another read only handle to the keyboards).